# While installing ubuntu 14.04. I lost my F drive(245GB)

Tags: 14.04, disk-management

I was trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 alongside windows 8.1. So I partition 20GB using 'Partition wizard software'. But the installation fails.So I wanted that 20GB to recover. But somehow my whole F drive(245GB) is lost now. Then I tried to create new partition using windows disk management. But it is asking me to format the drive before use[image3]. So I want to backup all data in the drive. What should I do? or is there any way to recover the whole drive with the data ?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the F: Drive is now in Liunx 83 format which windows cannot read, you'll need a 3rd party program in order access the files in that partition. Personally I like to use Linux reader, after you install the program, just copy the files from F: Drive to your windows partition and re-format the drive.

Alternatively you could pop in a Linux live usb and Copy the files from the F: Drive to your windows partition.

Answer (score 0):

If the F: Drive is in Linux 83 format (which I agree that it is), you can boot Ubuntu from USB or CD and run GParted to read it. Then, you can reformat it to be a Windows partition and the information should still be untouched. You might want to check on that last part because I've only ever had to try this once.